# Java streams limit the collection elements based on condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The below code, takes a stream, sorts it. If there is a maximum limit that should be applied, it would apply it.

```
if(maxLimit > 0) {
    return list.stream().sorted(comparator).limit(maxLimit).collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    return list.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

//maxLimit, list, comparator can be understood in general terms.
```

Here, inside if, limit operation is present and in else, it is not present. Other operations on stream are same.

Is there any way to apply limit when maxLimit is greater than zero. In the code block presented above, same logic is repeated, except limit operation in one block.

Comment: Could this be done with Java 9 `takeWhile()`? I guess the answer is no, since takeWhile operates on the stream and is stateless....!?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
list.stream().sorted(comparator).limit(maxLimit>0 ? maxLimit: list.size()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Looking at the current implementation of limit i believe it checks to see if the limit is less than the current size so would not be as inefficient as i initially expected

Comment: Correct and a cool idea, personally I would go with @szymon-stepniak solution as it's easier to read and still concise...

Comment: Thanks. Concise code. Solution wanted is for the question is pointed here.

Answer (score 17):

You can split your code into parts like:

```
final Stream stream = list.stream()
        .sorted(comparator);

if (maxLimit > 0) {
    stream = stream.limit(maxLimit);
}

return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case you don't have to maintain two branches as it was in your initial example.

Also when assigning `stream` variable it's worth using specific generic type, e.g. if `list` is a `List<String>` then use `Stream<String>` type for a `stream` variable.

Comment: Though the code is split, the operation on stream is only once. Even if the code was split, single operation on the list is needed. This solution is nice.